# How to allow Microsoft OneNote in Windows Firewall?

Tags: firewall, microsoft-onenote

I have a Windows Firewall set to block all outbound connections by default. I want to allow OneNote to go through.

Currently, I have these firewall process rules:

- %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE
- %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTEM.EXE
- %ProgramFiles% (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
- DNS

However, that's not enough. The syncing initially works, however after some time an error "We're having trouble syncing. Click "Sign in again" to fix this issue" appears and syncing no longer works. After clicking that button, a popup with Windows login appears, but after submit it says there is no internet.

When I set to not block all the outbound connection by default, the login works.

I suppose OneNote uses some other Windows feature to do the login.

What else do I need to allow in firewall so the OneNote works?

Comment: Blocking outbound connections is rarely necessary. I would set FW to Defaults, restart, test and then block only inbound connections you need to block.

Comment: Enable the firewall logging for blocked connections and see what gets denied. I believe the package that handles the account info for O365 is named Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin or Microsoft.AccountsControl. They are not typical .EXE files

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I've tried allowing those two packages, but haven't helped. I have also checked firewall log and looks like that responsible service is "wlidsvc - Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant". I have tried to create a firewall rule just for that service, but it doesn't seem to work - the packets are still being dropped by firewall for some reason :/ (when EXE rule is created for system32/svchost.exe, then it works, but it allows every service)

Comment: @user10099 Based on the built-in rules, you should set the filter to the program name `svchost.exe` *and* the service name together.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Doesn't work either. Have rule to allow "%SystemRoot%\System32\svchost.exe" AND "wlidsvc" service, but packets originated from  process with PID belonging to that service are getting dropped.

Comment: Also tried alternative suggested here: https://superuser.com/questions/1340301/windows-7-firewall-outbound-allow-rule-for-cryptsvc-not-matching .. instead of filtering the service by "Service" rule, filter the service by "Application Packages" rule and use the service ID .. but still nothing :/ .. with or without svchost.exe ..

Comment: It may be related to the "Windows services have been restricted with rules that allow expected behavior only. Rules that specify host processes, such as svchost.exe, might not work as expected because they can conflict with Windows service-hardening rules." alert that is displayed when submitting the rule with svchost.exe

Answer (score 0):

Blocking all outbound connections will cause Windows to work very badly.
This is absolutely not a good idea.

It is also unnecessary, as Windows Defender will ask you once, for each
new program, if to allow it the access to the internet.
You can then detect and control these new programs and stay safe.

Comment: Windows Defender will not ask for outgoing connections. It will only ask when programs want to accept _incoming_ connections.

Comment: Exactly as Daniel says. It would be really nice if Windows asked for outgoing connections as well. That way I wouldn't have these problems and also all neccessary Windows services could be allowed. But yes, I kinda agree with this "answer", there is lot of troubles and additional work when outgoing connections are blocked. Still would like to know what specifically the OneNote needs though.

Comment: @DanielB: Windows Defender asks for each new installed program on its first internet access if to let it access the internet on public networks or only on private ones. Windows has done that as far back as I can remember.

Comment: [This dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHa2n.jpg) is only about allowing incoming connections. It will not appear for outgoing connections, even if they were manually blocked.

Comment: @DanielB: In the example I see F.E.A.R. 3. This is not a server program and AFAIK doesn't listen on ports (or there would be some security concerns).

Comment: It’s a multiplayer game. It will listen for incoming connections. // I encourage you to try yourself. Download a server, maybe a VNC server. Put in a new location, because firewall rules created by this dialog are path-based. You will get the dialog. Now download a client, something simple. You will not get the dialog. It will just work, because Windows does not block outgoing connections by default. If you select to, Windows will not stop you and neither will it help or prompt to unblock applications.

Comment: @DanielB: In this [article](https://www.minitool.com/news/fix-windows-defender-firewall-blocked-app-features.html) the example product was Google Chrome. I don't think that it has incoming connections.

Comment: With WebRTC, browsers aren’t simple clients anymore. // I just remembered Windows ships with `curl` nowadays. Why not try with that: `curl https://superuser.com`. It will work, no firewall prompts. You can also check the list of allowed apps, it won’t be there.

Comment: @DanielB: There might be more complicated rules than just a list. Perhaps the digital signature of the executable. I have the feeling that some apps cause the dialog and others don't, but I never paid it that much attention.